# Why does my category dropdown become blank after selecting a service in my ASP.NET MVC web application using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Hy, my developer friends!
I am facing an issue in my web application project that is developed in C# in dotnet technology using MVC framework. The database is SQL Server. I am creating a booking form that allows the user to select Service and its category. The category dropdown list is dependent upon service input. See my code, why its not working correctly. The issue is that when I select a service the category dropdown become blank and shows no category to select.[image: Issue]

CREATE OF BOOKING

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Service_FID, "Service_FID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Service_FID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "updateCategories(this.value)" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Service_FID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category_FID, "Category_FID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Category_FID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category_FID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
        </div>
```

AJAX IN CREATE OF BOOKING AFTER DIVS

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function updateCategories(selectedService) {
        // Clear existing options in the second dropdown
        $("#Category_FID").empty();

        if (selectedService != "") {
            // Send AJAX request to fetch subcategories based on selected service
            $.ajax({

                url: "/Bookings/GetCategories",
                type: "POST",
                data: { Service_FID: selectedService },
                success: function (data) {
                    // Update the second dropdown with fetched subcategories
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        $("#Category_FID").append($('<option></option>').val(item.Category_ID).text(item.Category_Title));
                    });
                }
            });
```

CONTROLLER OF BOOKING FOR CALLING action

```
 public ActionResult GetCategories(int Service_FID)
        {
            // Fetch subcategories based on the selected service ID from the database
            List<Category> Categories = GetDataFromDatabase(Service_FID); // Replace Category with your model class name

            return Json(Categories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        private List<Category> GetDataFromDatabase(int Service_FID)
        {


            // Retrieve subcategories based on the selected service ID from the database using your data access logic
            // Return the list of categories

            // Example implementation:
            List<Category> categories = db.Categories.Where(a => a.Service_FID == Service_FID).ToList(); 
                //new List<Category>();
            // Implement your data access logic to fetch subcategories based on serviceId
            // Add the fetched subcategories to the categories list

             return categories; 
        }
```

I tried to use onchange function in dropdown and passed that id to ajax function and ajax function call the controller function. Please trace any logical error if any, I will be very grateful.